# C# - How do I put the Function Regex working?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Good morning,
I am doing a page for my intership and I found this function but it isn't working, can someone help?
Thank you in advance.

```
string _id = this.txtIdGrupo.Text;

if (!Regex.IsMatch(_id, @"^\d+$"))   
    return false;
```

The output says this:

```
error CS0103: The name 'Regex' does not exist in the current context
```

Comment: What did you learn when you did a web search for that error code?

Comment: @AdrianHHH - What's that "web search" you are speaking of?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0103

Comment: `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not an issue with the bit of code you showed.

This is a namespace issue at the very top of your file.

The solution should be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    
public class Test
{            
    public static void Main ()
    {
        var isNumeric1 = IsNumeric("1");
        Console.WriteLine(isNumeric1);

        var isNumeric2 = IsNumeric("HelloWorld");
        Console.WriteLine(isNumeric2);

        //call IsNumeric with the value of this.txtIdGrupo.Text like this
        //var isNumeric = IsNumeric(this.txtIdGrupo.Text);
    }

    private static bool IsNumeric(string str)
    {
        string id = str;

        if (!Regex.IsMatch(id, @"^\d+$"))   
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

See it in action:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/I7cAKs

notice the "using System.Text.RegularExpressions"

Using tools like Resharper and similar will definitely give you hints and will improve your day to day !

Comment: Ty for the answer, and I'll search for that toll then, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the `System.Text.RegularExpressions`
is imported

Comment: Oh ok, I actually didn´t had it, Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem anytime